# How can I set up a vm instance on google cloud but use my preferred username rather than name_domain_com or whatever goes there by default?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cloud, google-compute-engine

I just set up a new ubuntu vm "compute Engine" instance and the username at the ssh prompt is long. About a year or two ago I set up an instance and it just used the first part of my email address rather than the whole thing as my username. I have metadata set up like this:

```
enable-oslogin  TRUE
```

and ssh keys set up there with my regular username (first part of my email address).

But every time, it just uses my full email address (replacing the "@" and "." with underscores). I found a few links that point to IAM section of the console, but isn't there an easier way with fewer hoops to just choose the username you want? Obviously I could change it once I'm logged into the VM itself, but still, I'd like to not have to fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid that it is not possible to use a different user name as the OS login requires an email address. The underscores will always be present as all email addresses must contain both . and @ characters. This is part of the verification process of OS Login and cannot be changed and can be explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#login_messages)